# Why azure cdn returns me the old version of file with custom domain

Tags: azure-cdn, azure-caching

I have a file uploaded to my azure storage, and now I have replaced it with another version of this file.
The old file size was 22 mb.
now the new version is about 10 mb.
After replace when I try to download the file with my custom domain it still downloads the old file(22 mb).
But when I try to download with it's original url(storageName.blob.core.windows.net)
I get the correct file.

I have tried to set cache-control header 1 minutes using Microsoft azure storage explorer.

```
max-age=1
```

But it didn't help.

Why is such kind of behavior? And how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you try to Purge by providing the specific URI?

Comment: If be honest I don't know what Purge means, How can I do that or read from?
Can I do that with azure storage explorer?

Comment: When you navigate to the Azure CDN profile, you can see a button on the top. Purge actually flushes the cached data in the CDN.

Comment: But how azure caching behaves when updating existing data, I delete the file and upload the new file with the same name using storage explorer, and when I download the file with the custom domain url it downloads the old file.Why?
Where can I read about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a CDN configured with Azure Storage and you updated the file in Storage, CDN will still serve the cached old file until the TTL expires.

So you should either do a Purge or you need to configure the caching rules to get desired rules.

You can read more about Caching rules in CDN [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-caching-rules).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-purge-endpoint
Here it is described how to purge endpoint, but as I understand it clears the whole chace, is it possible purge only one file?
I wander am I doing anything wrong, because replacing a file is a very common. How can I have the updated file after the replace? what is the best practice
I think it is not normal to purge endpoint after every file change

Comment: Yeah, you can specify the path which you want to purge. By doing that only that path will be Purged.